# Subspace of R and spanned by S

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Really, I cannot solve questions like that because while solving these questions I cannot figure out difference between subspace and spanned ..

(a) Let $S = \{(1,−1,2,1),(0,3,−2,−2),(2,1,2,0),(1,0,−2,−3)\}$ and $W$ be the subspace of $R^4$ spanned by $S$ . Determine whether or not $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ is in $W$ .

(b) Find a basis for the solution space of $AX = 0$, where

$$ A= \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      1&0&2&1\\
      -1&3&1&0\\
      2&-2&2&-2\\ 
      1&-2&0&-3
    \end{array}
\right].
$$

[Here is original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZCPP.png)

Comment: subspace is a smaller version of vector space. Span means it can define every vector in that vector space.

Comment: @user29418 So, How can I solve it ?

Comment: can you get (1,2,3,4) as a linear combination from S?

Comment: The second one is a solve by Gaussian elimination. Augment the matrix to equal 0.

Comment: PS it follows that theorem: Span(S) is a subspace of a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

a) $a(1,−1,2,1) + b(0,3,−2,−2) + c(2,1,2,0) + d(1,0,−2,−3) = (1,2,3,4)$

Do there exist $a, b, c, d$ (from the field of Reals) such that the equation above is true?

1a + 0 + 2c +1d = 1

-1a + 3b + 1c + 0 = 2

2a -2b + 2c - 2d = 3

1a - 2b + 0 - 3d = 4

[you can set this up into an augmented matrix and do Gaussian elimination]

b) use Gaussian elimination

$$\left[
    \begin{array}{rrrr|c}
      1&0&2&1&0\\ 
      -1&3&1&0&0\\
      2&-2&2&-2&0\\ 
      1&-2&0&-3 &0
    \end{array}
\right].
$$

Answer Key:

a) should be no

b) 
$x_1 = - 2x_3$

$x_2 = - x_3$

$x_4 = 0$

$x_3 - free$

Comment: How can I be sure that there is such a b c d  ?

Comment: you have to solve a 4-way system of equations. And then use any method you want to solve it.